# Django Rest Framework SearchFilter doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement two filters in my `ViewSet` (`OrderingFilter` and `SearchFilter`), but only `OrderingFilter` works. I can see the proper control for `OrderingFilter` in the browsableAPI, but I don't get the proper control for searching.

This is my `ViewSet`:

```
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter, SearchFilter
from GeneralApp import serializers, models

class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CountrySerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)
    search_fields = ('name', 'code', 'calling_code')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is there any errors? because i don't understand why it happens

Comment: do you mean something like `http://example.com/api/countries?search=in` didn't get the desire result? will you show some result of such query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put comma after `SearchFilter` i think in this is the problem

```
filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, SearchFilter,)
```

Comment: Oh no, in fact, that's the way it was originally, but I removed the comma just to try. Thnaks any way

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the
search_fields or a filter_class:

```
search_fields = ('name', 'continent', 'language')
filter_class  = MyOwnClass
```